# Which Linux distributions support IPv6?

Tags: linux, ipv6

Which Linux distributions support the [IPv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) stack (like Windows Vista supports IPv6)?

Comment: What level of support are you asking about?  As many have mentioned it is supported in the kernel.  Support by particular applications may be more difficult to come by.

Answer (score 18):

The IPv6 Support has been in since Linux kernel 2.2, all modern distributions should have support for it.

Comment: You also have to have implementation in the network code as well as the kernel. That said, (K)Ubuntu has supported it for a few years, at least, and every major distribution I have looked at has supported it since 2004 (at the latest). Special, niche distros may not have support, but I don not know which those would be.

Comment: You may find http://www.deepspace6.net/docs/ipv6_status_page_apps.html useful to find out if a particular application has IPv6 support.

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu definitely supports IPv6 natively, and I'm fairly certain most other distros do as well. It might be more difficult finding ones that do not...

Comment: how is this getting downvoted? He said everything that others did

Comment: He also answered more accurately since OP wanted a distro and not a kernel number

Answer (score 4):

On 1996 the IPv6 support start in Linux kernel development version 2.1.8 and on 2005, Linux 2.6.12 removes experimental status from its IPv6 implementation.
So the IPV6 module is normally autoloaded on most recent Linux distributions default kernels (2.6.x)

Else when you have a custom linux kernel :

```
$ alias net-pf-10 ipv6  # will automatically load IPv6 module on demand
```

Answer (score 3):

Linux (the kernel) has had IPv6 support for a long time. Any current distribution should support IPv6.

Answer (score 1):

All 2.4 and 2.6 kernels, AFAIK, have IPv6 support. These kernels are in any standard Linux distro (even Slackware!) since about 2004, maybe even before.

Comment: Even Slackware? What's that supposed to mean?

Comment: Mr. Volkerding (the head Slackware maintainer) is known for including older software in Slackware on the basis that it's more stable. Slackware officially made the shift to 2.6.x in mid 2007 with the 12.0 release.

Answer (score 0):

All modern distributions should have support for it.